# Require.js to load same script on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm just learning about [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config). Lets say I have the following pages:

- pageA.html
- pageB.html

For page A, I need to load the following scripts:

- taco.js
- hamburger.js

For page B, I need to load the following scripts:

- taco.js
- salad.js
- superman.js

In order to do this using basic require.js loading, I think I would do this:

```
<!-- pageA.html contains:
<script data-main="/scripts/pageAScripts" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>
```

which is:

```
// pageAScripts.js
require(["/scripts/taco", "/scripts/hamburger"]);
```

and also

```
<!-- pageB.html contains:
<script data-main="/scripts/pageBScripts" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>
```

which is:

```
// pageBScripts.js
require(["/scripts/taco", "/scripts/salad", "/scripts/superman"]);
```

So now I have a main entry point for each page. But what I'm worried about is using `taco.js` in multiple places. Because when I use require.js's Optimizing solution in my build script, it creates `pageAScripts.js` (containing `taco.js`, `hamburger.js`) and `pageBScripts.js` (containing `taco.js`, `salad.js` and `superman.js`).

So now the code for `taco.js` is loaded twice for the user through the "optimization" process. In my case, `taco.js` is a pretty large file and having the user end up downloaded the data twice is undesirable.

What am I missing about the workflow here? I'm still pretty new to `require.js` so I'm sure there is something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example of the [multipage project](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage). Adapting the RequireJS build config there to yours:

```
{
    baseUrl: '.',
    dir: '../build', // This is where the output will go.
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'scripts/taco'
        },
        {
            name: 'scripts/pageAscripts',
            exclude: ['scripts/taco']
        },
        {
            name: 'scripts/pageBscripts',
            exclude: ['scripts/taco']
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a minimal adaptation of what the multipage project example provides. At the end of the build you'll have 3 bundles: `build/scripts/pageAscripts` that contains code only for page A, `build/scripts/pageBscripts` that contains code only for page B, and `build/scripts/taco` that contains only the taco module and all its dependencies.

Comment: So as I'm developing I'm only loading `pageAscripts` and `pageBscripts` but during my build process I need to add `taco.js` to be loaded by itself on my html pages since it's left out of the build? Is there an automated way to do that?

Comment: `taco` *is* part of the build. It is the first module in the list to which `modules` is set. Given what I see in the question, the only thing I'd expect having to change between development and deployment is where your pages are going to load their files from. At development time, you want to load the non-optimized files. At deployment time, you want to load the optimized files. If you start hitting special situations that require a different setup at deployment than during development, RequireJS does not provide support for this.

Comment: What happens if there are dependencies that both `taco` and `pageAscripts` uses? Is that dependancy compiled into both files in the end?  Also, how do I integrate jQuery into this? Is jQuery another module by itself that needs to be loaded by itself (like taco.js in this case) if all the pages use jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

You can load `taco.js` as separate file and in build file tell requirejs to not to include taco.js as part of build file. 
In you require config specify the path for `taco.js` -

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'taco': 'path/to/taco'
  }
});
```

And require `taco.js` in your `pageAScript.js` and `pageBScript.js` as follows -

```
require(['taco'], function (taco) {
});
```

And in your build file tell requirejs not to include taco as part of build file using `empty:`

```
({
   baseUrl: ".",
   name: "page(A/B)Script",
   out: "page(A/B)Script.js",
   paths: {
     taco: "empty:"
   }
})
```

You can find more about this [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty).

And now you can load the `taco.js` on `pageA.html` and `pageB.html` using script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/taco/js"></script>
```

Here `taaco.js` will be loaded for first page and for second page it will be loaded from browser cache.

Comment: Do I have to manually add the `<script>` tag to my html files during my build process? Or does require.js do this automatically when compiling?

Comment: And this will bomb with a [`mismatched anonymous define()`](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) error as soon as the browser processes `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/taco.js"></script>`.

Comment: ohh.. I thought taco.js is not a require module. sorry my fault.